# print the failed test output right after and not only at the end pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

I have multiple tests that run as part of a GitLab pipline, the issue is that the tests run became very long and when a test in the middle fails one need to wait to the end of the run to see the output of the failed test.

I'm using the following:

```
pytest -v -m -rxs --stepwise
```

Is there a way to print the failed test traceback right after it fails without doing the same for the passed tests

Comment: you can run `pytest -ff --maxfail=1`  this will just rerun the failed tests first and maxfail sets the number of tests that can fail before the testing stops.

Comment: @alexpdev but it do that after all the tests run already no? I want that if a spcific test fails the log will be printed right after it

Comment: yes once all the tests run, if any of them fail, you can run that command and it will rerun the first that failed and it's output only.... so it doesn't do exactly what you asked but it's close

Comment: @alexpdev it's close (thanks). I was thinking on maybe wrap it in fixture that will print the output directly after the run if it fails